# Jest. Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

Let's say I have MyFile.js

```
export const test2 = () => {}
export const test = () => {
  test2();
}
```

Then I have MyFile.test.js for it:

```
import * as MyFile from "./MyFile";

it("when test() is called should call test2", () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(MyFile, "test2");
  MyFile.test();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Why am I getting the error `Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called` for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) wraps the property of an object in a spy.

`MyFile` represents the module exports from `MyFile.js` so `jest.spyOn(MyFile, "test2");` wraps the *module export* for `test2` in a spy...

...but when `MyFile.test` gets called it calls `test2` directly so the spy never gets called.

---

One way to fix it is to move `test2` into its own module:

MyFile.js

```
import { test2 } from './OtherModule';

export const test = () => {
  test2();
}
```

OtherModule.js

```
export const test2 = () => {}
```

MyFile.test.js

```
import * as MyFile from "./MyFile";
import * as OtherModule from "./OtherModule";

it("when test() is called should call test2", () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(OtherModule, "test2");
  MyFile.test();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
})
```

---

The other way is to import the module bindings so you can call the module export for `test2`:

MyFile.js

```
import * as MyFile from './MyFile';  // <= import module bindings

export const test2 = () => {}
export const test = () => {
  MyFile.test2();  // <= call the module export for test2
}
```

MyFile.test.js

```
import * as MyFile from "./MyFile";

it("when test() is called should call test2", () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(MyFile, "test2");
  MyFile.test();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
})
```